# Detect end of div with jquery method not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to detect when the browser has scrolled all the way to the end of a div, to trigger an action when that occurs - add a class to the div `divToCheckEndOf`

I found a jQuery solution that checks for scrollTop and height of the window and document.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - divToCheckEndOf.innerHeight())) {
      divToCheckEndOf.addClass('abs');
    } else {
      divToCheckEndOf.removeClass('abs');
    }
});
```

This code works fine on large desktop resolutions, but it fails on laptop resolutions and mobile devices.

Any feedback appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was here, but I ended up using this good old jquery solution:

```
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > section.height() {
        //we are underneath the section
    }
```